# Wpf кнопка на tabcontrol

Tags: wpf, xml, c#-7.0

Есть `tabcontrol`(вкладка),на нем есть кнопка закрытия,но когда добавляешь `draganddrob`(перетаскивание вкладок) как в браузере,кнопка перестает работать.
в чем ошибка?
вот код xml

```
<TabControl  x:Name="TabCtrl" >
    <TabControl.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="TabItem">
            <Setter Property="AllowDrop" Value="True"/>
            <EventSetter Event="PreviewMouseMove" Handler="TabItem_Drag"/>
            <EventSetter Event="Drop" Handler="TabItem_Drop"/>
        </Style>
    </TabControl.Resources>
    <TabItem Header="Tab1">

        <TabItem.HeaderTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock Text="TabItem 1" />
                    <Button Content="Close" Click="ButtonBase_OnClick" />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </TabItem.HeaderTemplate>
        <Grid>
            <Label Content="TabItem 1"></Label>
        </Grid>
    </TabItem>
    <TabItem Header="Tab2">
        <TabItem.HeaderTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock Text="TabItem 2" />
                    <Button Content="Close" Click="ButtonBase_OnClick" />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </TabItem.HeaderTemplate>
        <Grid>
            <Label Content="TabItem 2"></Label>
        </Grid>
    </TabItem>
</TabControl>
</Window>
```

C#

```
 private void ButtonBase_DoubleClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        TabCtrl.Items.RemoveAt(TabCtrl.SelectedIndex);
    }
    private TabItem GetTargetTabItem(object originalSource)
    {
        var current = originalSource as DependencyObject;

        while (current != null)
        {
            var tabItem = current as TabItem;
            if (tabItem != null)
            {
                return tabItem;
            }

            current = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(current);
        }

        return null;
    }
    private void TabItem_Drag(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        var tabItem = e.Source as TabItem;

        if (tabItem == null)
            return;

        if (Mouse.PrimaryDevice.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
            DragDrop.DoDragDrop(tabItem, tabItem, DragDropEffects.All);
    }
    private void TabItem_Drop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        var tabItemTarget = GetTargetTabItem(e.OriginalSource);
        if (tabItemTarget != null)
        {
            var tabItemSource = (TabItem)e.Data.GetData(typeof(TabItem));
            if (tabItemTarget != tabItemSource)
            {
                int sourceIndex = TabCtrl.Items.IndexOf(tabItemSource);
                int targetIndex = TabCtrl.Items.IndexOf(tabItemTarget);

                TabCtrl.Items.Remove(tabItemSource);
                TabCtrl.Items.Insert(targetIndex, tabItemSource);

                TabCtrl.Items.Remove(tabItemTarget);
                TabCtrl.Items.Insert(sourceIndex, tabItemTarget);

                TabCtrl.SelectedIndex = targetIndex;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Решил сам,если вдруг у кого то такая же проблема.
дело было в том,что он перетаскивание и кнопка обрабатывалось одним событием `click` и поэтому он не понимал.решил проблему тем,что удаление происходит по двойному клику `MouseDoubleClick`